# Find $x,\, x',$ or $y$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-transformations

Analyzing two familiar equations, $y=a^x$ and $y'=mx'+b$. Where $x'$ and $y'$ are not $x$ and $y$ of the first equation. The exception being when the solution is found for $x$ and $x'$, that $y$ and $y'$ will then hold the same value. This condition can validate the solution.

I also have the inverse equations, $x=log_a(y)$ and $x'=\frac{y'-b}{m}$. Because $x$ and $y$ are not $x'$ and $y'$, we cannot transpose these equations to produce $x'=\frac{a^x-b}{m}$ or $x=log_a(mx'+b)$.

Ex. 1) $177147=3^{11}$ and $177147=35 \cdot 5061+12\quad (x=11, y=177147$ and $x'=5061, y'=177147)$

Ex. 2) $131072=2^{17}$ and $131072=77 \cdot 1702+18\quad (x=17, y=131072$ and $x'=1702, y'=131072)$

I need a solution to find $x$ and $x'$, where all variables are integers, with $y$ and $y'$ equating to the same value in both equations. $x$ and $x'$ are most like different but not a requirement.

Comment: I, hopefully, clarified the question. The solution to how to find x and x' must be something other than brute force, guessing, SWAG. It can be a binary tree, sampling a few results then extending trend lines, including imaginary numbers, convergent points, polynomial expansion, etc. but should be a legitimate algorithm. Also, trust that a, b, and m will always produce a solution. I'm hoping the solution doesn't require knowledge of the relation between these. If so, it will become a different question.

Answer (score 1):

It somewhat depends on the given values of $m$, $a$ and $b$. If both $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $m$, then of course you can choose any positive integer $x$ and calculate $x'=\frac{a^x-b}{m}$.

Another scenario where solutions exist is if $m$ is a prime, $a$ and $b$ are both coprime to $m$, and $b+m\mathbb{Z}\in\langle a+m\mathbb{Z}\rangle^*$ (within the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}^*$). In that case, you can find an $x$ such that $m$ divides $a^x-b$, and again $x'=\frac{a^x-b}{m}$ will give you a solution.

Comment: Both a and b will be smaller than m, so neither will be divisible by m. I'll review the other scenario when I get home, but think this doesn't answer the question if I need to search for an x such that m divides a^x−b.

Comment: @CarlKnox: Well, as I said, it depends on the concrete values of $m$, $a$, and $b$. For instance, if $a=4$, $b=2$ and $m=5$, then you're out of luck: If $5x'=4^x-2$, then $5$ must be a divisor of $4^x-2$ which simply doesn't happen for integral $x$.